# z-index problem with embed graph and calendar control

Tags: html

I am using embed graph and calendar control in same page. the calendar control is having z-index 999999.
But the calendar control appears below the graph.
How can i show calendar above embed graph.

Answer (score 0):

Add **position** to your CSS. For example:

```
#calendar-control {
  z-index: 999999;
  position: relative;
}
```